# Nftables rule to change default gateway for a packet

Tags: nftables

How can we change the default gateway for a packet.
Scenario:
Packet with destination 10.0.1.19  goes via default gateway 10.0.0.1
How can we force 10.0.1.19 to go via default gateway 10.3.0.1 using nftables

Comment: netmasks ,  interfaces ? It appears you intend for 10.3.0.1 to use another interface than 10.0.0.1 and it's also not clear if 10.0.1.19 is in the same network than 10.0.0.1 or not. You should give a reproducible example and not half of the values. The source of the packet (rather than just its destination) should also be given. `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` would give most of the configuration, and for good measure `ip neigh; ip rule` won't hurt too. If you already have a nftables configuration please also add `nft list ruleset`.

Comment: Is the "nftables" element of the question important, or can another feature (e.g. Linux Policy Routing) be used as a solution?  I think changing the default gateway for a packet with a specific destination would be relatively easy, using Linux Policy Routing.  The information requested by @A.B would also make the question easier to answer.